# How to change the Analytics Workspace of a VMSS in Azure?

Tags: azure, azure-monitoring, azure-vm-scale-set

The Azure Monitoring Agent is a service that runs on a virtual machine and sends logs and metrics to Azure Analytics. This agent can be installed via multiple ways, for example:

- by selecting the option while creating the VMSS, for example in the Azure portal
- with an "Enable" button in the monitoring section of a VMSS in case it was not installed while the VMSS was created
- by installing the the correct "extension" for all machines in the VMSS
- manually or automated as a software installation inside the virtual machine, for example via ansible or actually by hand

There might be more options, but in any case the agent needs to know to which Analytics Workspace it should send its data, and this value is a user input during the installation of the agent.

Now, once installed, how can I change the destination Analytics Workspace for an entire VMSS?

Answer (score 0):

There is no option to change the workspace. for the Virtual machines scale sets this support is limited as of now.